# Prevent Orientation change in Xamarin Android Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Is it possible to prevent the orientation of an Android application from changing ? I have an application that previews the phone camera and I would like the orientation not to change.

I have tried adding this to the manifest but it did not make a difference

```
<application android:label="TextureViewCameraStream" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    </application>
    <activity
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
```

I am using Xamarin for Android and C#

Thank you

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Set it in the Activity flag like this:

```
[Activity (Label = "YourActivityname", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Comment: Anybody else looking for an answer [for xamarin iOS as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=macos), it can be set in `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an Activity, and you want to keep your activity in the same orientation when it is opened, then use this label:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Locked)]
```